# OpenCV videos across platform

Tags: windows, linux, video, cross-platform, opencv

I am writing a video using **OpenCV** on Linux machine. I want to read the same video using **OpenCV** on a Windows machine. I am not able to do this using the standard codecs provided in **openCV**.

Can anybody suggest how I can read/write videos across the two platforms?

Answer (score 2):

The OpenCV Wiki directly addresses this issue. See [http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs](https://web.archive.org/web/20130524095153/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs) and specifically the heading "Compatibility list."

Unfortunately the only codecs supported on all three platforms (Linux, Windows & OSX) are 'DIB' 'I420' and 'IYUV' which are all uncompressed video codecs and thus make for really huge file sizes.

The wiki also lists some codecs to try that may work on any two platforms but not on all three.

If you decide to use uncompressed video files, you can convert them to something with a smaller filesize once they are on your windows machine using a program like [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/).

---

**Edit:** FYI, On Windows I have OpenCV output in Motion-JPEG and then I use VirtualDub in directstream copy mode to resave the file which corrects a bug with the movie's index. These M-JPEG video files then play by default on Mac and Windows.

If I am trying to read video *into* OpenCV, I often will first convert my video to Cinepak, (using virtual dub, quicktime etc.) and then feed it into OpenCV.  I use Cinepak because for some reason Cinepak encoders seem more prevalentthan MJPEG encoders.

Comment: How do you get opencv to be able to output Motion-JPEG? Mine crashes and says codec not available.

Comment: This is the relavent line of code that I use. I'm on Windows XP. `exp->Vid=cvCreateVideoWriter(MovieFileName,CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 30, cvSize(xdim ,ydim ),0);` I think (although I'm not positive) that the MJPEG encoder comes with OpenCV by default. I always assumed it was OpenCV's MJPEG implementation that was messing up the index file, which is why I have to do a second pass and direct-stream copy with VirtualDub before any other video player will read it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is with OpenCV, I think it is with codecs, as you mentioned. I also don't think OpenCV comes with codecs... double check that you have the proper codecs installed under Windows.

Did you look at the documentation on [video codecs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs)?